# Keras: how to access specific index for multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am building a function that multiplies input from one model branch in a particular way with inputs from another model branch, but accessing specific parts of the tensors isn't doing what I expect.

Minimal example: Imagine we get two tensors, one of which contains `[1, 2]` and the other `[10, 20, 30]` and one of the outputs should be `[1] x [10, 20, 30]` by taking the first value of the first tensor.

If I start by making variables like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Multiply    
x = K.variable(value=np.array([1,2]))
y = K.variable(value=np.array([[10,20,30]]))
```

Then I can access x[0] easily enough:

```
print(K.eval(x[0]))
```

gives: `1.0`

But it seems like that same indexing doesn't work for Multiply, as this code:

```
z = Multiply()([x[0], y])
```

Generates:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Thus the question: how can I access specific value indexes within a Multiply layer in keras (or how else can I do the equivalent)?

Comment: Could you show the full model?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko - I would love to, but it's hundreds of lines of code including some "customer confidential" stuff. That's why I made a minimal example that generates the error. Is there any specific piece of information you think would help? I'm basically trying to do full multiplication [a,b]X[c,d,e] = [ac, ad,ae,bc,bd,be]

Comment: But this is a part of `keras` model, right?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko - Yes, apologies for any lack of clarity. I have added the imports so the whole minimal example is ready to run without assuming anything about people knowing package abbreviations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show you an example of how one could achieve what you want. Let's assume that we have two inputs:

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(2,))
input_2 = Input(shape=(3,))
```

Now - let's define the following function:

```
def custom_multiply(list_):
    x, y = list_[0], list_[1]
    y = K.reshape(y, (-1, 1, 3)) # (1, 2, 3) -> ((1), (2), (3))
    x = K.reshape(x, (-1, 2, 1)) # (1, 2) -> ((1, 2)) 
    partial_result = K.batch_dot(x, y)
    return K.reshape(partial_result, (-1, 6))
```

Now - `output = custom_multiply([input_1, input_2])` should do what you've expected. Called on a pair `[(1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]` should return `(3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10)`.

Comment: Looks great! I need to get back to my desk to test and will mark as answer if works!

Comment: Verified! Works great, thanks! I hadn't found batch_dot in my searches and that's a neat bit of reshape syntax too.

Comment: That's great. Good luck with the further research.